# How can I elide a function wrapper from the traceback in Python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-2.x, traceback

## The issue

#### *The Phantom Menace*

Say i wrote a function decorator which takes the function, and wraps it in another function like so:

```python
# File example-1.py
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    # Do something
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do something
    # Do something
    return wrapper
```

Now  lets suppose the function I'm decorating raises an exception:

```python
@decorator
def foo():
    raise Exception('test')
```

The result of running `foo()` will print out the following traceback (In any Python version):

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-1.py", line 20, in <module>
    foo()
  File "./example-1.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-1.py", line 18, in foo
    raise Exception('test')
Exception: test
```

#### *Attack of the Clones*

OK, now i look at my traceback and i see it goes through the `wrapper` function. What if I wrapped the function multiple times(presumably with a slightly more sophisticated decorator object which receives arguments in its constructor)? What if I use this decorator often in my code(I use it for logging, or profiling, or whatever)?

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-1.py", line 20, in <module>
    foo()
  File "./example-1.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-1.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-1.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-1.py", line 11, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-1.py", line 18, in foo
    raise Exception('test')
Exception: test
```

I don't want it "polluting" my traceback when i know from the function definition that the wrapper is there, and i don't want it showing up multiple times when the code snippet it displays is the unhelpful `return func(*args, **kwargs)`

## Python 2

#### *Revenge of the Sith*

In Python-2, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603940/how-can-i-modify-a-python-traceback-object-when-raising-an-exception#answer-13898994) to a different question points out, the following trick does the job:

```python
# In file example-2.py

def decorator(func):
    # Do something
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        info = None
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            info = sys.exc_info()
            raise info[0], info[1], info[2].tb_next
        finally:
            # Break the cyclical reference created by the traceback object
            del info
        # Do something
    # Do something
    return wrapper
```

By directly wrapping the call to the wrapped function with this idiom in the same block as the function I want to elide from the traceback, I effectively remove the current layer from the traceback and let the exception keep propagating. Every time the stack unwinding goes through this function, it removes itself from the traceback so this solution works perfectly:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-2.py", line 28, in <module>
    foo()
  File "./example-2.py", line 26, in foo
    raise Exception('test')
Exception: test
```

(Note however that you can not encapsulate this idiom in another function, since as soon the stack will unwind from that function back into `wrapper`, it will still be added to the traceback)

## Python 3

#### *A New Hope*

Now that we have this covered, lets move along to Python-3. Python-3 introduced this new syntax:

```
raise_stmt ::=  "raise" [expression ["from" expression]]
```

which allows chaining exceptions using the `__cause__` attribute of the new exception. This feature is uninteresting to us, since it modifies the exception, not the traceback. Our goal is to be a completely transparent wrapper, as far as visibility goes, so this won't do.

Alternatively, we can try the following syntax, which [promises to do](http://python3porting.com/differences.html#raise) what we want (code example taken from the python documentation):

```python
raise Exception("foo occurred").with_traceback(tracebackobj)
```

Using this syntax we may try something like this:

```python
# In file example-3
def decorator(func):
    # Do something
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        info = None
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            info = sys.exc_info()
            raise info[1].with_traceback(info[2].tb_next)
        finally:
            # Break the cyclical reference created by the traceback object
            del info
        # Do something
    # Do something
    return wrapper
```

#### *The Empire Strikes Back*

But, unfortunately, this does not do what we want:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-3.py", line 29, in <module>
    foo()
  File "./example-3.py", line 17, in wrapper
    raise info[1].with_traceback(info[2].tb_next)
  File "./example-3.py", line 27, in foo
    raise Exception('test')
Exception: test
```

As you can see, the line executing the `raise` statement shows up in the traceback. This seems to come from the fact that while the Python-2 syntax sets the traceback from the third argument to `raise` as the function is being unwound, and thus it is not added to the traceback chain(as explained in the docs under Data Model), the Python-3 syntax on the other hand changes the traceback on the `Exception` object as an expression inside the functions context, and then passes it to the `raise` statement which adds the new location in code to the traceback chain (the explanation of this is very similar in Python-3).

A workaround that comes to mind is avoiding the `"raise" [ expression ]` form of the statement, and instead use the clean `raise` statement to let the exception propagate as usual but modify the exception objects `__traceback__` attribute manually:

```python
# File example-4
def decorator(func):
    # Do something
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Do something
        info = None
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            info = sys.exc_info()
            info[1].__traceback__ = info[2].tb_next
            raise
        finally:
            # Break the cyclical reference created by the traceback object
            del info
        # Do something
    # Do something
    return wrapper
```

But this doesn't work at all!

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-4.py", line 30, in <module>
    foo()
  File "./example-4.py", line 14, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./example-4.py", line 28, in foo
    raise Exception('test')
Exception: test
```

#### *Return of the Jedi(?)*

So, what else can i do? It seems like using the "traditional" way of doing this just won't work because of the change in syntax, and I wouldn't want to start messing with the traceback printing mechanism (using the `traceback` module) at the project level. This is because it'll be hard if not impossible to implement in an extensible which won't be disruptive to any other package that tries to change the traceback, print the traceback in a custom format at the top level, or otherwise do anything else related to the issue.

Also, can someone explain why in fact the last technique fails completely?

(I tried these examples on python 2.6, 2.7, 3.4, 3.6)

EDIT: After thinking about it for a while, in my opinion the python 3 behavior makes more sense, to the point that the python 2 behavior almost looks like a design bug, but I still think that there should be a way to do this kinda stuff.

Comment: Not fully qualified to understand the question, but +1 for the effort :)

Comment: Thanks! ^_^ I've been tracking this problem for about a week now.

Comment: The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908998/758174) by @Kyuuhachi is the one thing that finally worked for me. I had to make very minor changes, so in my context [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418463/758174) shows what I am now using.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that you shouldn't do that.  Hiding things from the traceback is dangerous.  You may think you don't want to show that line because it's trivial or "just a wrapper", but in general you wouldn't write the wrapper function if it didn't do something.  Next thing you know there is a bug in the wrapper function which is now unfindable because the wrapper function has erased itself from the traceback.

Just deal with the extra lines in the traceback, or, if you really want, override `sys.excepthook` and filter them out at the top level.  If you're worried about someone else overriding `sys.excepthook` too, then wrap all your code in a top-level function that does the exception printing itself.  It isn't and shouldn't be easy to hide levels from the traceback.

Comment: If you look at the `# Do something` comments I put in, I specifically placed them around the proposed idiom, so that any other exceptions show up as usual. I'm only interested in skipping the wrapper when the call is trivial.

Comment: If i use `sys.excepthook` i lose that fine grained control over when i specifically elide it, because if the wrapper calls other functions as well, it's non trivial to distinguish when an exception happened in the wrapped function and when it happened in another function.

Comment: Hiding parts of the traceback is dangerous, but in a few rare cases, you might decide it really is worth it. For example, `importlib` has its own [ugly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L196) [hacks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/import.c#L1278) in place so `importlib` frames usually don't show up in the traceback when something goes wrong during an import.

Comment: @Re.po: Even if that line is trivial, that doesn't mean it's a good idea to suppress the whole frame.  For instance, the decorator may, on earlier lines, change the arguments or even the function being called, so that an exception raised by the call line may have its real cause elsewhere in the wrapper.  This can't be seen if the entire frame is suppressed.  That said, if you google around you'll see people suggesting imitating [jinja2](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/5b498453b5898257b2287f14ef6c363799f1405a/jinja2/debug.py), which effectively reimplements traceback objects.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but i am specifically referring to the case where i change neither `func` nor `args` or `kwargs`. As for jinja2, this is exactly the sort of over-implementation i want to avoid. I prefer the implementation to be as simple and straightforward as it can be. I have an idea involving `sys.excepthook` that would use a helper module and will still be non intrusive to other code (by simply wrapping the original function with something else). I'll post an edit with the idea later if i figure it out and have time to write it.

Comment: Can you use `try` and `except`? If it will result in an error it will hide the error message by not completing the code that results in the error

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that?

Answer (score 1):

The internal `_testcapi` module contains a binding for the `PyErr_SetExcInfo` function, which makes this fairly easy to implement. Only tested on cpython 3.9; there's no guarantee that it'll continue working in the future.

```py
import functools
import typing as T

A_Callable = T.TypeVar("A_Callable", bound=T.Callable[..., T.Any])

try:
    from sys import exc_info
    from _testcapi import set_exc_info
    def silent_wrapper(f: A_Callable) -> A_Callable:
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args: T.Any, **kwargs: T.Any) -> T.Any:
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                tp, exc, tb = exc_info()
                # Drop two frames, one for silent_wrapper itself and one for the
                # wrapped function
                set_exc_info(tp, exc, tb.tb_next.tb_next) # type: ignore[union-attr]
                del tp, exc, tb
                raise
        return T.cast(A_Callable, wrapper)

except ImportError:
    def silent_wrapper(f: A_Callable) -> A_Callable:
        return f
```

Comment: Yes! Lovely hack. Why two frames though? My understanding is that we want to remove just the decorator from the trace. When I remove just one frame, then I get exactly that (i.e. the exception comes from the wrapped function).

Comment: Been a while since I made that, but iirc that's a decorator to be used on other decorators to hide them from the trace. So you need to drop both the frame crated by the decorator in question and the one created by `silent_wrapper` itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. Very nice. I was looking for the "simple" way where the decorator wants to remove itself, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418463/758174).